# Using AD as authentication for Django

Tags: python, django, active-directory, ldap

I'm working on a Django-based application in a corporate environment and would like to use the existing Active Directory system for authentication of users (so they don't get yet another login/password combo).  I would also like to continue to use Django's user authorization / permission system to manage user capabilities.

Does anyone have a good example of this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's another more recent snippet (July 2008, updated Dec 2015):

[Authentication Against Active Directory (LDAP) over SSL](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/901/)

Comment: Is there any more recent update about the AD authentication with Django? I am using Django 1.5. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

The link provided by Jeff indeed works though it assumes you have a you have a default group where users are added to.  I simply replaced:

```
group=Group.objects.get(pk=1)
```

by

```
group,created=Group.objects.get_or_create(name="everyone")
```

If you want tighter integration & more features there is also [django-auth-ldap](http://packages.python.org/django-auth-ldap/) which gives you you more control over how ldap users/group are mapped onto django users/groups.

For debugging the ldap connection I found [this blog post](http://www.djm.org.uk/using-django-auth-ldap-active-directory-ldaps/) useful, in particular the command for testing the ldap connection with ldap-utils:

```
ldapsearch -H ldaps://ldap-x.companygroup.local:636 -D "CN=Something LDAP,OU=Random Group,DC=companygroup,DC=local" -w "p4ssw0rd" -v -d 1
```

If you are using ssl there is also the issue of getting hold of a certificate will play nice with.  Either you extract it from the server, or you can follow [these instructions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321051) to generate your own.

Answer (score 5):

How about that? Did you try that one?

http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/501/

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, and noticed that django-auth-ldap does not support SASL at all -> plain text passwords over the connection if TSL is not available.

Here is what i did for the problem:
https://github.com/susundberg/django-auth-ldap-ad

Answer (score 5):

You can subclass the `django-auth-ldap` backend to add AD capabilities over with SASL or Kerberos or whatever. Here's a 2018 example working in Django 2.1:

https://partofthething.com/thoughts/authenticating-and-populating-users-in-django-using-a-windows-active-directory-and-sasl/